# Remove key list inside object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, list, loops, object

I need to remove the key: "incomeTax" inside of this structure how can I do that?

```
const hash: HashDetail = {
            arrTitle: [
                { date: 'Data', supporter: 'Apoiador', document: 'Documento', plan: 'Plano', payment: 'Pagamento', incomeTax: 'I.R.', value: 'Valor' }
            ],
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the key using:

```
delete arrTitle[0]. incomeTax
```